# Can I combine chain and group without a results backend?

Tags: python, celery

I like to combine a chain and a group in a small workflow of immutable tasks and without a results backend.

However, when I try this Celery automatically converts it to a chord and then complains that there is no results backend.

Is there any way I can get this to work without a results backend?

Code:

```
@shared_task
def test_canvas():    
    workflow = chain(group(test_task_a.si(), test_task_b.si()), test_task_c.si())
    workflow.delay()
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
raised unexpected: NotImplementedError('Starting chords requires a result backend to be configured.
Note that a group chained with a task is also upgraded to be a chord, as this pattern requires synchronization.
Result backends that supports chords: Redis, Database, Memcached, and more.',)
```

Interestingly, running a chain or a group by itself works just fine.

Example:

```
workflow = chain(test_task_a.si(), test_task_b.si(), test_task_c.si())
workflow.delay()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think that the answer is no - you can't run chord without [backend](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chord-important-notes):

> Tasks used within a chord must not ignore their results. In practice this means that you must enable a result_backend in order to use chords.

Your first example in `test_canvas` is implicitly `chord`:
A chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a group have finished executing ([link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords)).
If you think about the logic behind (well expalin [here](http://blog.untrod.com/2015/03/how-celery-chord-synchronization-works.html)) 
 someone (backend) need to figure out when all parallel tasks ended (the group) to know when it should trigger the next (chained) task.

In the second example, running multiple tasks concurrently with `group` is simple (nothing to coordinate later if no action should be taken).
Same for the `chain` - each task is responsible for triggering the next one, no complicated coordination is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It confirms my prior understanding, but if you don't mind I'll leave this question open for a bit longer in the hope someone else might have another idea.